# Removing spaces and commas from uploaded filename

Tags: php

After using this code for a while, I've found that people are uploading files with spaces and commas.

I've tried the function `reg_replace`, and the filename uploaded is in fact edited having spaces replaced with underscores as supposed.

I would also need to tell the final file name to the user, so I would need to have that file name inside a textfield that is echoed if upload is successful. This last part is what is missing.

How could this be done within the following context?

```
<?php

$target_dir = "extra_images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\"><strong>File already exists.</strong></div>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 3750000) {
    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\"><strong>Your file is too large.</strong></div>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

//Check for pdf format
if (!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'])) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
    if (($mime != 'application/pdf') && ($mime != 'image/jpg') && ($mime != 'image/jpeg') && ($mime != 'image/gif') && ($mime != 'image/png')) {

        $uploadOk = 0;
        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\"><strong>This file is not a valid file.</strong></div>";

        //exit();

    }} //this bracket was missing I think


// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\"><strong>The file was not uploaded.</strong></div>";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {

    $target_file = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $target_file);//to replace spaces...

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {

        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\">The file <strong>". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). "</strong> has been uploaded.</div><br>Please copy this filename: <span class=\"form-inline\"><input type=\"text\" value=\"". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). "\" class=\"form-control input-sm\" style=\"width:220px;\" /></span> And paste it in an empty Extra image field above and save the form.";
    } else {
        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">There was an error uploading your file.</div>";
    }
}
echo "</br></br><p><button class=\"btn btn-default pull-right\" style=\"margin-right:5px;\" type=\"submit\" onclick=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span> Back</button></p>";
exit();

?>
```

Comment: imo, Record the original file name, timestamp, the user id and the 'sanitized file name' somewhere. A database is fine. Rename the file to include the 'sanitized details' in a standard format so that you can easily find the original details.

Comment: Thank you for the idea but I know very little about php or any object oriented language, I learned pascal and a little of C...

Answer (score 1):

You can use str_replace() to change space into underscore.

```
$str = 'hai welcome';
$newstr = str_replace(' ', '_', $str);
echo $newstr;
```

Now you got output without space;

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I meant in the code I supplied that already has a function to replace space... `$target_file = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $target_file);//to replace spaces` this function is saving the name with underscore already but I also need to show that filename inside a textfield in the echo if upload successful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I´ve managed to put it to work, it now saves the filename to the database which was one of my other needs. The user ip capture also works but only with the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; variable I wonder how to use the get_client_ip(). Tried to save the $ipaddress to the db field but did´t worked... Thank you for your ideas and help.

```
<?php

                $target_dir = "images_folder/";
                $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
                $target_file = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $target_file);//to replace spaces...
                $uploadOk = 1;
                $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                // Function to get the client IP address
                function get_client_ip() {
                    $ipaddress = '';
                    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
                        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
                    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
                        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
                    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
                        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
                    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
                        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
                    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
                        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
                    else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
                        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                    else
                        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
                    return $ipaddress;
                }
                $ipaddress2=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

                // Check if file already exists
                if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\"><strong>File already exists.</strong></div>";
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }
                // Check file size
                if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 3750000) {
                    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\"><strong>Your file is too large.</strong></div>";
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }

                //Check for pdf format
                if (!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'])) {
                    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
                    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
                    if (($mime != 'application/pdf') && ($mime != 'image/jpg') && ($mime != 'image/jpeg') && ($mime != 'image/gif') && ($mime != 'image/png')) {

                        $uploadOk = 0;
                        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\"><strong>This file is not a valid file.</strong></div>";

                        //exit();

                    }} //this bracket was missing I think


                // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
                if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\"><strong>The file was not uploaded.</strong></div>";
                // if everything is ok, try to upload file
                } else {



                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {

                        $cleanFilename=basename("$target_file");

                        // Connects to your Database
                        mysql_connect("localhost", "db_username", "db_pass") or die(mysql_error()) ;
                        mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error()) ;

                        //Writes the information to the database
                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName (filename,ipaddress)
                        VALUES ('$cleanFilename', '$ipaddress2')") ;


                        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\">The file <strong>". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). "</strong> has been uploaded.</div><br>Please copy this filename: <span class=\"form-inline\"><input type=\"text\" value=\" $cleanFilename \" class=\"form-control input-sm\" style=\"width:320px;\" /></span> And paste it in an empty Extra image field above and save the form. If you see the image after saving you've done right. $cleanFilename";
                    } else {
                        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">There was an error uploading your file.</div>";
                    }
                }
                echo "</br></br><p><button class=\"btn btn-default pull-right\" style=\"margin-right:5px;\" type=\"submit\" onclick=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span> Back</button></p>";
exit();
?>
```